# How to Check Check boxes in java using one go

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, checkbox, awt

I have a List of Check boxes. Think suppose I have 100 elements in the list each associated with a check box. Now i need to select the elements starting from 50 to 100, i.e, the check boxes associated with 50th element to the 100th element have to be checked. It is very difficult to check each and every check box from 50 to 100 (i.e, total 51 check boxes) manually. Can anybody please let me know how can i check these 51 check boxes in a single go.

Comment: you can use javaScript to do that.

Comment: Are those check boxes in a swing application or on a web application?

Comment: @user3381955, you can have a checkbox let say `Select All`, write script that will check/un-check other 51 boxes as per its state i.e. checked or un-checked

Answer (score 0):

One solution to your problem might be to get a range entered by user, say by presenting them two text fields and then select each checkbox in the range programtically.

Answer (score 0):

From the tag AWT I deduce you are in a Java Swing/AWT environment. If that's the case you can create an `ArrayList<JCheckBox> (Swing)` or `ArrayList<CheckBox> (AWT)` and add every chechbox to it when created (in NetBeans IDE for Swing/AWT perspective I think there is an "add code after creation" box in the *code* tab). Then you can have a method like this

```
private boolean checkMyBoxes(int first, int last){
    for(int i=first; i<=last; i++)
        if(!arrayOfCheckBoxes.get(i).isSelected()) return false; //Swing
      //if(!arrayOfCheckBoxes.get(i).getState()) return false; AWT
    return true;
}
```

---

**EDIT**
I think I misread the question. You don't want to check if the boxes are checked, you want to "check" them.
You can still use the method above with some modifications

```
private void withCheckIMeanCheckMyBoxes(int first, int last, boolean state){
    for(int i=first; i<=last; i++)
       arrayOfCheckBoxes.get(i).setSelected(state); //Swing
      //arrayOfCheckBoxes.get(i).setState(state)); AWT
}
```